# Struggling to find loop invariant in power function

Tags: correctness, loop-invariant, proof-of-correctness

I am struggling to find a good loop invariant for the following function, which returns a^b where a is a real number and b is a natural number:

```
power <- function(a, b){
     c <- 1
     while(b > 0){
          if(b %% 2 == 1){
               c <- c * a
          }
          b <- floor(b / 2)
          a <- a * a
     }
     return c
}
```

I've ran through the loop with a couple of examples, and I see that it has 2 kinds of cases; when b is even or odd. I also understand that on the kth iteration, a = a_0^(2^k), but I am struggling to find a proper invariant as there is no real iterating variable to use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the invariant to be useful, it will have to have `c = a_0^b_0` as a special case after the while loop terminates, which occurs when `b = 0`.

For the invariant to be true, we have to get `a_0^b_0` on the left hand side before the first iteration. We already know the left hand side has a `c` in it, and before the first iteration `c = 1`, so multiplication seems like a good idea.

Whatever we multiply by must end up being 1 after the loop terminates, which (as before) occurs when `b = 0`. Getting something to equal 1 when `b` is 0 suggests we want `b` to be an exponent, and the desired `a_0^b_0` on the left hand side also suggests `b` should be an exponent.

Putting this all together, the invariant will either be `c * a_0^b = a_0^b_0` or `c * a^b = a_0^b_0`. I will leave it to you to determine which one of those is correct, and to prove that it is in fact invariant.